# What do various values of "fun" do when rasterizing a query?

Tags: rasterize

I'm wanting to rasterize a polygon (shapefile; values of `1` and `2`; `1 = outside a protected area`, `2 = inside a protected area`), to a 1 minute resolution raster.

I'm using rasterize.

Can anyone please tell me what does using `fun= first` or `fun= last` mean?
Each one produced a slightly different outcome. I can't find any explanation anywhere. Results are also slightly different to if I use `fun=min, max, mean`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   I've put more information into the title of your question to attract more attention.   I've also improved the formatting to make it easier to read and to clearly show which bits are the code.

Answer (score 3):

As an example lets say that I measure the height and location of every tree in a forest. I could display those data in a variety of ways but lets say I want to create a raster of tree height.

Depending on the resolution I choose for my raster each grid cell could contain several trees.  However, each grid cell can only have a single value for tree height so I need to decide how to deal with having multiple trees, each with a value for it's height, within a cell.  This is what the various functions allow me to do.

Depending on my hypotheses I could want the `mean`, `median`, `mode`, `maximum` or `minimum` of the tree heights in each grid cell of my raster.  I might also want to know how many trees are in each grid cell, in which case I can use the `count` function.  The `first` and `last` functions do pretty much what they say on the tin.  If you imagine that all the tree heights for a single grid cell are a vector then `first` selects the first value in this vector and `last` selects the last value in the vector.

In ecological terms I can't think of why this might be useful but I experimented and that's what they do.  As an aside there isn't actually a `mode` function when using `rasterize` but you can write a custom function easily enough.  Hope it helps!

Comment: If you want to capture the variability of all possible values across space, `last` (which is essentially choosing one value randomly) would be useful. `Mean` and `median` converge towards central values, `maximum` and `minimum` clearly converge towards extremes.  Capturing variability in a raster dataset is important for modeling, perhaps not as useful in data analysis but some ecological processes are indeed sensitive to variability in values. (@James if you think this is useful, feel free to grap this text for your post)